# Would a phrase modifying an adjectival be considered an adverbial?

Tags: phrases, grammatical-roles

For example, in "There are two sequences meshed together":
-"two sequences" is a phrase functioning as an adjective and therefore an adjectival.
-"meshed together" is a phrase modifying "two sequences" which is a noun phrase.

**So what happens when a phrase modifies a noun phrase or noun that is an adjectival?** Is it considered an adverbial or adjectival?
My wavering notion is that when using words like "adjectival" or "adverbial", I am doing an analysis beyond phrase analysis.

Phrase analysis = figuring out the phrase types in a sentence based on composition.
Something like this:
[image]

Comment: What or who tells you that "two sequences" functions as an adjective?

Comment: What did you find when doing your research? E.g., how is "adverbial" defined?

Comment: This question can’t be answered as asked; two sequences is a noun phrase functioning like a noun does — not like an adjective does.

Comment: Among other difficulties, it appears you are trying to use *together* as though it were a reciprocal pronoun like *each other*. Gears mesh together, but sequences combine with each other. DNA and RNA sequences *bind* during polypeptide construction (which is an odd word-choice from a gearhead point of view).

Answer (score 2):

> (**CoGEL §15.45**) **Correspondence with basic clause patterns**
> There is a regular correspondence between existential sentences with *there +
> be* and clauses of equivalent meaning as specified in terms of the basic clause
> patterns […], provided that the clause concerned
> (i) has an indefinite subject […]; and
> (ii) has a form of the verb *be* in its verb phrase.
> Allowing for these two requirements, we may relate basic clauses to existential forms by means of a general rule:
> [subject + (auxiliaries) + be + predication]
> ~ [there + (auxiliaries) + be + subject + predication]
> The subject of the original clause may be called the 'notional' subject of the
> *there*-sentence, so as to distinguish it from *there* itself, which for most
> purposes is the 'grammatical' subject […]. […]
>
> Type SVC
> Something must be wrong. ~ There must be something wrong.

- There are two sequences meshed together.
  *Two sequences are meshed together.*

SVC: subject verb complement;  "meshed together" is the subject complement, an adjectival phrase.

"Two sequences" is the *notional subject* of the existential, therefore it is a noun phrase.

Adjectives can be immediate constituents of a clause or of a noun phrase;  you  recognize which it is on the basis of the understanding you gain from the study of clause structure and noun phrase structure..

Comment: newbie question: why do we use "there are"? Is it just used as a starter of an explanation?

Comment: @nobdyjustaenglish In the words of CoGEL, "there are" is used because it has "the effect, […][as a] prelude,  to postpone to a more 'focused' position the noun phrase "two sequences meshed together", which, because it ushers in new information, can only uneasily fill the unfocused position of subject".

Answer (score 1):

> *There are two sequences* [*meshed together*].

Here, the bracketed element modifies "sequences". But it's not functioning as an adjective; rather, it's a non-finite clause. Not everything that modifies a noun is a noun or noun phrase!

> *Perhaps you will never find* [*a job as a linguist*].

Here, the bracketed element is a noun phrase functioning as object of "find". The preposition phrase "as a linguist" is complement of "job".